# Angular 2 unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello i am absolute beginner into Angular2, i just set some application but i got error  **angular2-polyfills.js:390 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import(…)**
Please help me to resolve this.
I created app.component.ts file into same name space as main.ts
here is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Acme Product Management</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="app/app.component.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'ts'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Starter files for Angular2: Getting Starteddd.
<pm-app>Loading app...</pm-app>
</body>

</html>
```

app component file

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector:'pm-app',
    template: `<div>{{PageTitle}}</div>`
});
export class AppComponent{
    pageTitle:string = 'Ovo je string';
}
```

main ts file

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';

// Our main component
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Help i am new to Angular2 please help

Comment: I guess you are using angular 2 beta version, try out upgrading to latest `rc` mentioned here on angular.io

Comment: please check node > 4.x

Comment: Angular 2 is now production: 2.0.0  Be careful looking at any examples.  If you're new, I suggest going to angular.io.  Lots of examples have obsolete syntax, references, etc.